# Confusion in finding the definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries

So, I'm new to Mathematica. I tried evaluating the following definite integral. However the answer i get from wolfram alpha & mathematica are different.
Can someone please point out what I'm missing?
The answer from wolframAlpha is correct according to Casio fx-991-es

```
Integrate[1/(1 + t) ((t + 0.8)/(t + 1))^20, {t, -0.8, 0}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste copy&pastable code instead of screenshots. It is not fair to the people who are trying to assist to make them need to retype all your content based on some images.

Comment: oh I'm sorry Integrate[1/(1 + t) ((t + 0.8)/(t + 1))^20, {t, -0.8, 0}]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precision issues. Use one of the following instead.

Symbolic integration:

```
Integrate[(1/(1 + t)) ((t + 4/5)/(t + 1))^20, {t, -4/5, 0}]
(*-(318650448087859023644/198221683502197265625) + Log[5]*)

N@%
(*0.00189205*)
```

Numeric integration with a higher working precision:

```
NIntegrate[(1/(1 + t)) ((t + .8`20)/(t + 1))^20, {t, -.8`20, 0}]
(*0.00189205*)
```

Comment: Usually when do these issues occur?  should i use NIntegrate instead?

Comment: These issues appear when [machine precision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html) numbers are insufficient for the precision needed to accurately compute what you require.

Comment: There's a ton of doc pages on these topics. Here's another useful one: [Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html)

Comment: Appreciate your help Thanks!

Comment: Also note that in the `NIntegrate` call I suggested I changed more than just adding the N in front of Integrate.

Comment: @RamithHettiarachchi -- (1) Note further that if you do just add an N in front of your `Integrate[..]`, you get the same answer as the `NIntegrate[..]` in this post.  Higher precision is unnecessary in the numerical integrator.  (2) Symbolic solvers such as `Integrate` often have trouble with "inexact" floating-point input. (3) Interesting aside: ``Integrate[(1/(1 + t)) ((t + .8`20)/(t + 1))^20, {t, -.8`20, 0}]`` caused my kernel to crash! So even with high-precision approximate inputs, exact solvers may still have problems.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I’d report that kernel crash

Comment: I noticed that kernel crash as well when I was playing with it yesterday (it's the 0.8\`20 in the integrand that causes the crash; it's fine with the 0.8\`20 in the lower limit of integration), and put in a report to Wolfram.